# Reverting single file in SVN to a particular revision

Tags: svn, revert

I have a file as shown below in an SVN repo that I would like to revert to a previous version. What is the way to do this in SVN? I want only downgrade this particular file to an older version, not the whole repo.

Thanks.

```
$ svn log myfile.py
----------------------
r179 | xx | 2010-05-10

Change 3
----------------------
r175 | xx | 2010-05-08

Change 2
----------------------
r174 | xx | 2010-05-04

Initial
```

Comment: when you said revert, what did you mean, 7 years ago, lol

Answer (score 191):

If you just want the old file in your working copy:

```
svn up -r 147 myfile.py
```

If you want to rollback, see this "[How to return to an older version of our code in subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814433/how-to-return-to-an-older-version-of-our-code-in-subversion)".

Comment: but the next time you update it gets the file you didn't want back... :S

Comment: if you don't want it back, svn commit that file, to put the version you want into the repo

Comment: This probably does not actually do what the question asker wanted.  Using this, the working copy is clean and cannot be committed AS IS, and an "svn update" without a version number specified will retrieve the latest, unwanted version.

Comment: How can I commit the reverted file then?

Comment: This isn't quite right because, as CXJ mentions, there isn't a way to commit the updated file.  You probably want to do as Mitch Dempsey says (note, however, the --force to force overwriting the file): svn export --force -r 147 myfile.py myfile.py

Comment: It is not complete. I've moved the file to file.old, did svn up again, moved file.old to file (overwriting the original) and finally committed.

Comment: If you want to roll back an individual file and be able to commit, then do: 'svn merge -c -[OldRev#] [Filename]' ie. svn merge -c -150 myfile.py.

Answer (score 102):

svn cat takes a revision arg too!

`svn cat -r 175 mydir/myfile > mydir/myfile`

Comment: **This is by far the best answer on the page.** It leaves the changed file in a state that can be committed.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when you are pasting into a new file

Comment: haha looking back at it, idk what context i was thinking of when i posted. I can't recall. It does seem nonsensical.

Comment: This is simple and straightforward for when you simply want to undo your changes and get a file back into it's pre-commit state without any version control technicalities.

Answer (score 58):

```
svn revert filename
```

this should revert a single file.

Comment: What's up with all the other answers with longer commands? Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I have no idea what is up with other answers.. lol

Comment: they're up, and they're longer. i concur.

Comment: explanation for down voting?

Comment: This reverts to which revision? Doc says just replaces with latest in repo. Question is how to revert to an earlier version.

Comment: This reverts to the latest version of repo. If you read the description of the questions, it seems like he was looking for how to revert a single file, not entire directory.

Comment: I believe all this does is destroy your working copy by 'reverting' it back to head.  Or to which ever was checked out.  confirm by doing svn update -r VER file, then do an svn revert.

Answer (score 50):

For a single file, you could do:

`svn export -r <REV> svn://host/path/to/file/on/repos file.ext`

You could do `svn revert <file>` but that will only restore the last working copy.

Comment: export, then paste it to your local copy, then commit it again?

Comment: @tgkprog that is one way to do it, yes

Comment: @tgkprog and what is the "preferred" way?

Comment: No idea but that is what worked for me :  exported past revision. Opened in notepad, copied, pasted in to working file. Committed that to head with comment on which rev and why. UI tools might have a better way.

Answer (score 27):

So far all answers here seem to have significant downsides, are complicated (need to find the repo URI) or they don't do what the question probably asked for: How to get the Repo in a working state again *with that older version of the file*.

`svn merge -r head:[revision-number-to-revert-to] [file-path]` is IMO the cleanest and simplest way to do this. Please note that bringing back a *deleted* file does not seem to work this way[1]. See also the following question: [Better way to revert to a previous SVN revision of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345997/better-way-to-revert-to-a-previous-svn-revision-of-a-file)

[1] For that you want `svn cp -r [rev-number] [repo-URI/file-path]@[rev-number] [repo-URI/file-path] && svn up`, see also [What is the correct way to restore a deleted file from SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490522/what-is-the-correct-way-to-restore-a-deleted-file-from-svn)

Comment: I wish to remark that at least for my version of Subversion, `svn merge` does not take multiple files as an argument for some reason. In this case it seems to do just nothing (without an error message).

Comment: But my command still works by repeating it for each file, right?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: Agreed that this is the cleanest.

Answer (score 13):

The best way is to:

```
svn merge -c -RevisionToUndo ^/trunk
```

This will undo all files of the revision than simply revert those file you don't like to undo. Don't forget the dash (`-`) as prefix for the revision.

```
svn revert File1 File2
```

Now commit the changes back.

Answer (score 11):

You want to do

`svn merge -r [revision to revert from]:[revision to revert to] [path/filename]`

Once you do that, you will have that revision of the file in a committable state.  Commit the file.

Answer (score 9):

surprised no one mentioned this

without finding out the revision number you could write this, if you just committed something that you want to revert, this wont work if you changed some other file and the target file is not the last changed file

```
svn merge -r HEAD:PREV file
```

Comment: if you have comments please discuss here before making edits?

Comment: Doesn't the scenario in the question require a reverse-merge of the most recent change, such that we should apply the changes needed to go from HEAD to PREV?

Comment: The command should be `svn merge -r HEAD:PREV file` as @Nick Russo said

Answer (score 7):

I found it's simple to do this via the `svn cat` command so that you don't even have to specify a revision.

```
svn cat mydir/myfile > mydir/myfile
```

This probably won't role back the inode (metadata) data such as timestamps.

Comment: then commit the file so it goes to the repo

Comment: This worked for me better than update. Because update does not let you commit the modification made to that file. (svn 1.8.3)

Answer (score 5):

If it's only a couple of files, and if you're using Tortoise SVN, you can use the following approach:

1. Right click on your source file, and select "TortoiseSVN" -> "Show log".
2. Right click on a revision in the log, and select "Save revision to...".
3. Let the old revision overwrite your current file.
4. Commit the overwritten source file.

Comment: This saves a new unversioned file such as file-xxxx wherein xxxx is the old revision number. What we do next? delete the new revision (HEAD e.g.), rename the new file, add, commit?

Comment: No, don't save it with the revision number in the file name. Save it with exactly the same file name as the current version of the same file (in other words, no xxxx in the file name). Then just do an ordinary commit after that.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding on to @Mitch Dempsy answer since I don't have enough rep to comment yet.

```
svn export -r <REV> svn://host/path/to/file/on/repos --force
```

Adding the --force will overwrite the local copy with the export and then you can do an svn commit to push it to the repository.

Comment: and this is the best answer :)

Comment: why is this the best answer? it doesn't manage history the "svn way"

Answer (score 2):

An alternate option for a single file is to "replace" the current version of the file with the older revision:

```
svn rm file.ext
svn cp svn://host/path/to/file/on/repo/file.ext@<REV> file.ext
svn ci
```

This has the added feature that the unwanted changes do not show up in the log for this file (i.e. svn log file.ext).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to roll back an individual file from a specific revision and be able to commit, then do:

svn merge -c -[OldRev#] [Filename]

ie. `svn merge -c -150 myfile.py`

Note the negative on the revision number