# svn update -r of single file deletes the file

Tags: svn

I wanted to revert a single file to a specific revision. I quickly found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812901/reverting-single-file-in-svn-to-a-particular-revision) that might have been the perfect way to do so, but it doesn't work as expected.

The command `svn diff -c 36118 path/to/MyFile.java` outputs

```
Index: path/to/MyFile.java
===================================================================
--- path/to/MyFile.java   (revision 36117)
+++ path/to/MyFile.java   (revision 36118)

@@ -57,21 +57,21 @@
                if (cause != null) {
                        s = s + " " + cause.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + cause.getMessage();
                }
-               List<String> liste = createMessageList(s);
+               List<String> list = createMessageList(s, 4);
                Exception exception = null;
```

and so on. You clearly see that from revision 36117 to revision 36118 I only changed some lines but neither added, removed or renamed the entire file.
However, as I run

```
svn up -r 36117 path/to/MyFile.java
Updating 'path/to/MyFile.java.java':
D    path/to/MyFile.java
Updated to revision 36117.
```

subversion deletes `MyFile.java`. Why? I don't understand what is going on ...