# How to restore a deleted file in svn repository [ Not in my working copy ]?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I deleted some specific folders(entire content of - bin,obj,pkg from visual studio solution) and some specific files from my working copy and then committed so they got deleted from the repository too. I know I can update my working copy to previous revision and they all come back in my working copy.

But how will they come back in repository ? So that when others take update they get those deleted files.

When I commit after updating my working copy to previous revision, then I get tree conflicts.

Comment: Maybe those links will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490522/what-is-the-correct-way-to-restore-a-a-deleted-file-from-svn OR

http://www.simonwheatley.co.uk/2009/04/29/restoring-deleted-files-from-an-svn-repository/
 OR
http://www.canfield.com/content/svn-restore-deleted-file

Comment: I have already gone through these links...but they talk about restoring in the working copy.. I want those files and folders back in my SVN Repository itself.

Comment: restore them locally and commit?

Comment: btw, there is nothing important in `bin` and `obj`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
svn copy http://domain.tld/repo/path/to/file@42 .
```

Where `42` is the revision you want the file need to be restored at.

After that just perform commit

Comment: @zerkms: I deleted around 53 bin,obj and pkg folders each in separate solution in a main root solution and then committed. There have been changes to other files also after that.

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja: so? My answer will work regardless count of changes.

Comment: @zerkms: First thing, I need a method from the tortoise GUI, I don't have command line client. Second, do I need to fire this command 53*3 times for each folder ? And what about the other changes that were made after these deletions to other files, will not these be lost ?

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja: update to `HEAD` and do all that. From guy that is available from `repository explorer` (iirc, haven't installed it)

Comment: What is this iirc ? Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja: If I Remember Correctly ;-)

Comment: Thats what my initial question was: I just right click my working copy folder->Tortoise Svn->Update to revision->Select revision and then update. This will update my working copy only. And then when I commit it - it doesn't happen and I get tree conflict errors.

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja: :-S Your working copy should be `HEAD`. Copy from old revision, but current should be the latest