# How to get deleted file from SVN Repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

I deleted a file from my Eclipse work space but that file is in **SVN repository**. Could any one help me to get my deleted file from **SVN** without using the command line?

Comment: are u using tortoise svn ?

Comment: I just Tried. When i click on SVN HISTORY on a folder. I see Deleted Files. AM susing Subversion Plugin in Eclipse. Under Revision, If i click on 'D' rows, they show deleted code/file

Comment: this may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490522/what-is-the-correct-way-to-restore-a-deleted-file-from-svn

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy,I can able to see deleted file.But my question is how to get back that to my own workspace?

Comment: From Vinod's Link...                                                  Use the Tortoise SVN copy functionality to revert commited changes:

Right click the parent folder that contains the deleted files/folder
Select the "show log"
Select and right click on the version before which the changes/deleted was done
Select the "browse repository"
Select the file/folder which needs to be restored and right click
Select "copy to" which will copy the files/folders to the head revision
Hope that helps

Comment: if you have simply deleted the file from local working copy but haven't committed yet, simply do a revert and undo your delete action will solve the problem.

Comment: Right CLick on Deleted Items, say COPY... it creates back those files.. works for me

Answer (score 4):

There's a simpliest way to recover the file with Eclipse+SVN only.

Go to SVN Repositories view, find a folder your file was located, make a right click and choose Show History. You will see the list of commits to **THIS FOLDER** in the History view. Please make sure it's switched to Remote Revisions. From the list of commits find a commit that deleted the file. In the pane below there's a list of files involved with this commit - you can find deleted files with minus sign. Double click will open this file in editor...

Answer (score 1):

If you've deleted the file in Eclipse, Eclipse has told Subversion to mark the file for deletion. This means the next commit will delete the file. You'll have to do a *revert*.

If you've deleted this file via Internet Explorer or some other file browser, and didn't tell Subversion, then the file isn't marked for deletion. Simply *updating* the file will bring it back.

This is where the command line client sings. With the command line client, I could tell Subversion to update or revert a nonexistent file. With a GUI, I would first have to *select* the file, then tell Subversion what to do. But without a file, I can't do anything.

Easiest solution: Recreate the file. The contents are not important. It can be empty or contain a dirty limerick for all you care. You're basically making a file you can select with your file browser.

Then, you can select the file and tell Subversion and/or Eclipse via the Team menu to *revert* it. This way, it doesn't matter how the file was deleted. Subversion will restore the file back to its original checked out version.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Bryn's solution, using Subclipse, find the delete 'D' entry for the file in SVN history, right-click and do "Copy..." which will then ask you to specifiy a location in your Eclipse workspace. Click OK, it will probably take a little while, and that's it.

[image]

I first tried "Export...", but that didn't work for me, seems like subclipse is looking in HEAD, even though an older revision was selected.