# Recover overwritten file by Tortoise

Tags: android, svn, tortoisesvn

I've been working a few days on many classes of an Android Project before doing a commit to Tortoise SVN. The thing is that I updated my project before doing a commit. So far, Tortoise have never overwrite my modified classes, but this time it did. How can I recover all the work I did the past days?

Comment: In my experience, doing the work a second time is always faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to restore a deleted file from SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490522/what-is-the-correct-way-to-restore-a-deleted-file-from-svn)

Comment: I don't think is the same thing, that question is about files on repository, mine is about files on my local working copy overwritten by the ones on the repository

Answer (score 1):

You can't rollback to state "modified, but not committed WC". Period

**If** you can to detect, *which* revisions exactly bring to your WC this update, you can *try* to [reverse merge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reverse%20merge%20[svn]) this range in WC. If you can't - you FAILED, but get experience:

- **NEVER update without previous commit of your WIP**
- **NEVER update blindly, know incoming updates**